# Merging tuples with same head in list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list composed by tuples.

Each tuple is in the following tuple format: (String, Integer).

I want to merge the tuples that have the same head (String) as follows:

```
[("Foo", 2), ("Bar", 4), ("Foo", 2), ("Bar", 4), ("Foo", 2)]
```

should become:

```
[("Foo", 6), ("Bar",8)].
```

What is a good python algorithm for this?

Comment: Please show how you've attempted to solve the problem to begin with. StackOverflow isn't a site to write code for you. You don't learn anything from that.

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about collecting the sums in a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for (key, value) in items:
  d[key] += value
```

And then turn them back to a list of tuples:

```
list(d.items())
```

The `defaultdict` in this example uses the `int` function to fill in unknown values as `0`. So the first time a particular `d[key]` is added to, it assumes an initial value of `0` and gets summed from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
map(lambda (x,y):d.setdefault(x,[]).append(y),a)
print [(k,sum(v))  for k,v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [("Foo", 2), ("Bar", 4), ("Foo", 2), ("Bar", 4), ("Foo", 2)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for tup in my_list:
    key, value = tup[0], tup[1]
    d[key].append(value)

lst = [(key, sum(value)) for key, value in d.items()]

result = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: x[1])

print(result)
```